# kendo radio button value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've following code in razor view. How do I use Kendo Radio button to render the same? Mainly, I'm struggling to assign `enum` value to radio button value.

```
@if (Model == declaredEnum.​Val1)
{
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(l => l, (int)declaredEnum.​Val1, new { @checked = "checked" });

}
else
{
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(l => l, (int)declaredEnum.​Val1);   
}
@Html.LabelFor(l => l, "Label")​
```

**Edit**
Definition of `Enum`

```
Public Enum declaredEnum
{
 Val1,
 Val2
}
```

There is another radio button with the same code, but it checks for `val2`. Current logic is working fine. I just need to convert to `Kendo` control instead of `razor`.

Comment: Is this in some kind of loop (makes no sense on its own). You don't set the  `checked` attribute - its set by the helper based on the value of the property. Show your definition for the enum.

Comment: You creating only one radio button which makes no sense (if it is selected it can never be unselected). I assume this must be an `EditorTemplate`. You need 2 radio buttons - `@Html.RadioButtonFor(l => l, "Val1" )` and `@Html.RadioButtonFor(l => l, "Val2" )`. If the model value is `declaredEnum.Val1` then the first one will be selected, otherwise the second one will be.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes you are right. There are 2. Other one is same but using `val2`. But I just put only one in question. If I can convert one. I can convert second one as well. I'm not worried about logic. It is working fine with current code. Just want to rewrite in Kendo, as it is requested by my superior.

Comment: But you don't need any `if` block and you don't need to convert to an `int` and you definitely don't set the `checked` attribute. Your binding to a property so its the value of the property which determines which of the 2 radio buttons are selected

Comment: I've to save 1 or 2 in database based on the selected radio button. That's why I need the enum..

Comment: It will save `1` or `2`! (but if you want to use `(int)declaredEnum.​Val1` rather than `"Val1"` then fine), but the other comments stand - you should not have an if block

Comment: I'll work on `if` block. But, I'm struggling with assigning  `value` to kendo radio button

Comment: It you inspect the html for the the code in my previous comments, you will see it has the values set - `<input type="radio" ...value="Val1" />` and `<input type="radio" ...value="Val2" />`. You have not shown what you have tried for the Kendo buttons, but it would be something like `@(Html.Kendo().RadioButtonFor(l => l).Name("Val1").Label("Val1"));`

Comment: this is generated html `<input class="k-radio" data-val="true" data-val-required="Primary Contact is required" id="Val1" name="Val1" type="radio" value="true" />` for above radio button

Comment: OK, that's no good because the name attribute needs to be what ever your property name you binding to is (but I don't know what that is, or if your using an `EditorTemplate`) - try dropping the `.Name("Val1")` bit

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this post is very old, but I am working with Kendo UI for the first time and needed to figure this out for myself. The following code snippet creates a radio button group called "name-of-radio-group" from an enum with two values. It defaults the first radio button to checked:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    @Html.Label(Enum.GetNames(typeof(declaredEnum)).ToList()[0], new { @class = "col-sm-2" })
    @(Html.Kendo().RadioButtonFor(m => m.declaredEnum).Checked(true).Name(Enum.GetNames(typeof(declaredEnum)).ToList()[0])
          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "col-sm-1", name = "name-of-radio-group"}))

    @Html.Label(Enum.GetNames(typeof(declaredEnum)).ToList()[1], new { @class = "col-sm-2"})
    @(Html.Kendo().RadioButtonFor(m => m.declaredEnum).Name(Enum.GetNames(typeof(declaredEnum)).ToList()[1])
    .HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "col-sm-1", name = "name-of-radio-group"})
    )
</div>
```

In my example I only had two enum values so I did not feel the need to use a loop, instead I just indexed the enums directly. In case it is not clear to someone the m.declaredEnum represents a property on a strongly typed model where the property name is the same as the name of the enum.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But we had so many other issues with kendo. So, moved away from it.